# Why is my h2 database empty every time my Spring Boot application starts?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, h2

I'm using spring boot in a maven project with the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency.

In my application.yml file I have:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:./data;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

I also have a DataPopulation class with :

```
if (userRepository.findAll().iterator().hasNext()) {
  // Database already has users..
}
```

Where userRepository is a CrudRepository instance.

On every start up the userRepository returns no users, regardless of how many were added the last time the application was running.

I can see that the data.mv.db and data.trace.db files are created and not empty.

Why is my database always empty on start up?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was nothing wrong my jdbc string.  Spring boot uses 'create-drop' as the default hibernate ddl-auto value.

I resolved the issue by adding:

```ini
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

to my properties.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Quick resolution for me =)

Answer (score 4):

The `./data` path makes me think the database is getting deleted each time you build the application, as `.` means the current directory. So you could use a database file relative your your user home folder, indicated by `~`: `~/data`. You also may want to use `:file` in the JDBC URL:

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:file:~/data;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

In case you need, check the H2 [features documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html).

Comment: I tried using ~ instead.  I can see the file is now created in my user directory.  However the application behaviour is the same.  No users found.

Answer (score 2):

As per https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database, by default data.sql gets executeed ahead of Hibernate initialisation. Therefore, we have to defer datasource initialisation as given below. This ensures that the data is populated after the schema is generated.
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

Following is my working application.properties

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.sql.init.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:lee
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

Comment: It was not like that before. Looks like something got changed. However thanks for the info which made things work for me again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the url in this form:

```
jdbc:h2:file:<dbpath>
```

example

```
jdbc:h2:file:/opt/db/mydb
```

to persist your data.

Comment: I'm not sure about Hibernate, but `jdbc:h2:./data` and `jdbc:h2:file:./data` have exactly the same meaning in H2 by itself.

Comment: I have tried both with and without the file: bit in the jdbc string. The behaviour is the same in both cases.

Comment: Thanks dude fro the help